# JSoup Authentication Required Dialog

Tags: java, xml, authentication, jsoup

I'm trying to implement JSoup API for parsing XML, but I'm having problem authenticating with **Authentication Required Dialog**. Is there a way to implement this in JSoup?

Original Code:

```
HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
http.getState().setCredentials(org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope.ANY, new org.apache.commons.httpclient.NTCredentials(userName,password,url,domain));
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to authenticate using JSoup, but I managed to create a work around. What I did is to implement **org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient** and **org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod** for connecting and getting the DataInputStreamReader. The DataInputStreamReader will be passed to JSoup, so we can use JSoup for parsing the xml/html. See the code below:

```
// codes 

GetMethod method      = new GetMethod(url);

// passing the credentials
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.getState().setCredentials(org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope.ANY, new org.apache.commons.httpclient.NTCredentials(username,pass,url,domain));

Document doc = null; // org.jsoup.nodes.Document

if( http.executeMethod(method)==200){
    doc = Jsoup.parse(new DataInputStream(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()), "UTF-8", url);
}

// codes
```